# where to relabel a application pod in Prometheus operator?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus-operator

In Prometheus operator,where to relabel a application pod?

Is additionalPrometheusRules: the place where we can relabel? https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/values.yaml

Answer (score 0):

In each scrape.

You may refer to[relabeling tricks](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config)

or official doc: [officail relabel docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config)

Comment: Thankyou..I tried relabeling in servicemonitor and I am able to view the new target label in service discovery.However i am unable to view the new label in the alerts in Prometheus.How to reflect the new label change in alerts?

Comment: Have you seen this: [alert_relabel_configs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#alert_relabel_configs) ? @Rad4